# Is there an application that will move an active window to the system tray without minimizing it

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, notification-area

I have an active application (lets say an instant messaging client) whose buddy list I have up (active) on one side of my screen at all times in Windows 7.

I would like to remove that icon from the taskbar either by moving it to the system tray (as happens when the app is minimized)  or by just removing it altogether.

To be clear:

I do not want to minimize the window to the system tray (as described in [How can I hide an application from the Windows taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/43206/windows-app-to-hide-application-from-taskbar))

I want to *keep* the window its NORMAL size and location and just get rid of the taskbar icon for the app.

I'm looking for any tool, third party, native, registry hack, to accomplish this.

Comment: If this is for an instant messaging client, which one is it?  Most have this as an available feature built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried *Taskbar Hide* and I swear a zillion other freeware apps.  The only one I could find that would allow both "Hiding of running taskbar entries" and "putting apps in system tray" **without minimizing** is this application called *Actual Windows Manager*.

Its a little weird as you'll need to make individual profiles for each application and you'll want to disable all the other features of the app (like Tabbed Explorer).

The two "rules" that need to be used in tandem (per app) are **Startup>Remove Taskbar Entry** and **Minimizing>Tray Icon: Permanent**.  This will get rid of the taskbar entry and show an icon in the system tray **even when the Window is active**.  When minimized it will also be just a tray icon.  Clicking the tray icon will restore the app and keep the icon in the tray.

Works in win 10, doesn't work on some Win 10 "apps".
You can add applications by drag and drop from the Specific Settings menu>Add New Window Rule (Green Plus Button).

[Application List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HevGb.png)

[Per App Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kRrS.png)

Be sure and hit apply on the Specific Settings Window.

Comment: Awesome, but I'm afraid the free version has a trial period of 60 days only.

Answer (score 2):

If the particular application you want to hide from the Taskbar doesn't specifically allow you configure this, then you may have other options:

- Make use of software named "Taskbar Hide" (download link: http://www.eusing.com/hidewindows/bosskey.htm),
- Make the Taskbar icon invisible for that application (instructions here: http://www.maketecheasier.com/hide-application-icon-in-windows-7-taskbar/).