# How can I disable the Taskbar / Tool Tray icon of an application?

Tags: taskbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows application to hide an application from the taskbar](https://superuser.com/questions/43206/windows-application-to-hide-an-application-from-the-taskbar)

I have a program on my computer that displays both a taskbar and a tool tray icon. I only need the tool tray icon. Is there a way I can turn off the taskbar icon?

The program itself does not have an option for this.

Comment: Which operating system and version? Please edit your question to include this detail.

Answer (score 2):

Not within windows.
You can choose which icons to see/hide in the notification area, but the presence of a taskbar icon is only definable in the application options or through a third party app - not sure if any exists for Windows7 but apps like [Taskbar Shuffle](http://nerdcave.webs.com/) and Power Menu have shown that it is possible.

Check the answer here:
[How can I hide an application from the Windows taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/43206/windows-application-to-hide-an-application-from-the-taskbar)