# How can I hide a Window from the task switcher (Alt+Tab)?

Tags: windows, desktop

To make clear what is this question about, this is the Windows Task Switcher:

[image: TaskSwitcher]

The closest to **hide a window** from the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> Task Switcher that I have found is the [Minime](http://sourceforge.net/projects/minime-tool/?source=typ_redirect) tool, but it hides too the window from desktop, and I only need to hide its Task Switcher instance.

I **need to see the window** on the desktop, but I would like to hide it only from Task Switcher.

Some tools like those referred in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/43206/how-can-i-hide-an-application-from-the-windows-taskbar) have same behavior.

Is there any method?

Additional Points:

- Hiding the window from the **TaskBar** is not relevant here. It does not bother me whether it is or not there.

**Why** could I need that? [The Bat](https://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/thebat/)! from RitLabs is a good email client, and has a fancy extra window named **mail ticker** for unread mails:

[image: The Bat! mail ticker]

But I never write into this mail ticker window or use it (I never need it to **get focus**). So its presence in the Task Switcher is undesired for me.

The simplest method will be preferred.
Open source tools preferred. Privative code and even not free ones accepted.
Methods for any Windows version are preferred. At least for Windows 7, please.

Comment: So you don't want the program window minimised to the notification area but just want it gone from the Alt+Tab list? Is there a reason why? Perhaps using a [multiple desktops utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc817881.aspx) and moving the app to a different virtual desktop will help?

Comment: @Karan, added explanation. Some multiple desktop tool would not help, as long as I need the window on the screen. I would prefer some shorter method, like this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/437090/hiding-an-application-from-switcher-alttab for Gnome. Maybe some register change, or any other minor tool running at boot.

Comment: If you make it appear in the system tray (notification area) and thus remove it from your taskbar, it should also be removed from the alt-tab list. Alt-Tab is only showing you the programs that are active on the taskbar.

Comment: @LPChip , I actually have uTorrent v3.4.2 running and in the system tray (keeps on the taskbar), but the task switcher still shows it. Furthermore: the mail ticker window (from the above mentioned The Bat) is not on the task bar, but is still shown too on the task switcher.