# Windows 10 - virtual desktop startup automation

Tags: windows-10, powershell, virtual-desktop

I've not been able to find much on this so I thought I'd ask here:

I am looking for a way to have multiple virtual desktops created on logon and a few applications automatically started in each. For instance I typically have a chrome browser in each desktop. I then typically have a dev virtual desktop (sublime, pycharm, firefox, and a few other thigns), I then have a news/social desktop (irc, slack, skype, gchat, evernote with my 'to read' list, and so on) and then finally a 'workstuff' desktop with onenote and a few other apps.

I know, worst case scenario I can create a macro to do this but I was wondering if there were any additional controls in Windows which let you manage multiple desktops as I think it'd be incredible if I could have my work, dev, social, etc. desktops automatically populate with the correct apps after reboots instead of having to redo it every time :)

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the application [VDesk](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk).

> [VDesk for Windows 10: launch programs on virtual desktops](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/06/15/vdesk-virtual-desktops-windows-10/)
>
> Vdesk is a portable program for Windows that adds the feature to
>   Windows 10. It is a command line program but ships with an option to
>   integrate its functionality in File Explorer.
>
> The main command looks like this: `vdesk [n] [command [args]]`
>
> - **n** sets the index of the virtual desktop you want to launch the program on.
> - **[command [args]]** specifies the program and arguments that you want it to start.
>
> The command `vdesk notepad.exe` launches Notepad on a new virtual
>   desktop, while `vdesk 3 notepad c:\text.txt` opens Notepad on virtual
>   desktop 3 and uses an argument to load `text.txt` automatically.
>
> [You can run](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/11/28/how-to-autostart-programs-during-windows-log-on/) the application on start of Windows 10 to always load
>   programs on virtual desktops when the operating system starts by
>   creating simple batch files, and adding them to one of the many
>   [startup locations of the operating system](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/06/04/windows-automatic-startup-locations/).
>
> The option to launch a program on a new virtual desktop can be added
>   to File Explorer as well. You need to run *vdesk -install* for that on
>   the command line, and will notice afterwards that a new "open in new
>   virtual desktop" option is available when you right-click on
>   executable files in File Explorer.
>
> The command *vdesk -uninstall* removes the entry from File Explorer
>   again.

Comment: vDesk creates the application in the current desktop and then moves it. The launched app might eventually flash in the current desktop, which may or may not be of concern.

Comment: Just an FYI. VDesk utilizes the native multiple desktops that Windows 10 offers, it does not implement its own original virtual desktop solution, which is good. It is written in C# and relies on the VirtualDesktop (https://github.com/Grabacr07/VirtualDesktop) library, making it usable from a terminal/script. VirtualDesktop is a C# wrapper around IVirtualDesktopManager (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ivirtualdesktopmanager?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Answer (score 3):

As of right now, there is only a few limited keyboard and mouse controls for Windows 10's virtual desktops.  I looked, hoping to find PowerShell commands... but unfortunately, not.

Since you specifically stated "on startup," You can write a script to do this using the keyboard commands.  In the scripting language of your choice, start the apps you want on the first desktop.  Then send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win Key</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to move to the next desktop.  Then start your next applications.  Repeat as necessary.  Obviously, you will have to test this.  You may have to insert some pauses, or whatever, but it should work.

Comment: @Abraxas No problem.  I noticed I left out the ctrl key, added that to the answer

Comment: @Abraxas, you could investigate the [AutoIt Cmdlets for Windows PowerShell](https://www.autoitconsulting.com/site/scripting/autoit-cmdlets-for-windows-powershell/) for sending the keys as Keltari describes.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple script that allows you to start a bunch of items in one go (on different desktops):

https://github.com/SuperflyJon/FileStarter

Turns out that lots of apps startup in their own special way, so no guarantees this script will work for everything and it's a bit fiddly to setup lots of items...

Answer (score 0):

To keep this up to date, and for anyone else that arrives via Google, there's another solution if you have an NVidia graphics card.

You can use the NVidia RTX Desktop Manager.  You can create profiles within this that will open desktops and programs as you wish.  You can save down multiple profiles and set one to open on startup and assign shortcut keys to profiles too.

Quite useful in the scenario you described.