# Windows 10: How to save a virtual desktop session?

Tags: windows-10, desktop, window-manager, virtual-desktop

I work on multiple projects involving many different tools and therefore windows in my taskbar.

I use the virtual desktop feature of Windows 10 to avoid having a messy desktop.

I can let my laptop go to sleep when I close it (without losing my desktop sessions), and I can switch between sessions when I am working on specific projects.

But what can I do for rebooting, applying updates, or simply turning off the computer?

I would like to be able to save each instance of a running virtual desktop and then relaunch them with all their associated applications and windows (e.g. IntelliJ + Firefox + ... for one desktop).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: My workaround is to create a few chrome profiles and assign each profile to a given desktop. But then it's another hassle, since you might have to synchronize bookmarks, history, etc. And chrome only allows one Google account per profile, so it has to be a third party tool rather than chrome's built-in sync. Many layers of hacks, so only partial satisfaction ;-)  As far as apps, such a bummer, I haven't found any way.

Comment: The script from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1477582/8672) of mine might help.

Comment: Is VMs an option?  You could have several VMs, one for each project.  When you close the VM, it saves the current state.  You can open it 5 years later and it is exactly where you left it, even the half sentence that you were typing before it was saved.

Comment: Have you considered using hibernate?  I go months without shutting down my computer/laptop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the application [VDesk](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk) this way:

1. You configure VDesk to automatically create N new Virtual Desktops when opened;
2. You configure VDesk to automatically open your applications on each Virtual Desktop;
3. You set VDesk to autostart with Windows;

∴ Each time you login on Windows, all pre-configured Virtual Desktop sessions will be opened, each with their respective programs.

How to use VDesk?

> The main command looks like this: `vdesk [n] [command [args]]`
>
> - `n` sets the index of the virtual desktop you want to launch the program on.
> - `[command [args]]` specifies the program and arguments that you want it to start.
>
> The command `vdesk notepad.exe` launches Notepad on a new virtual desktop, while `vdesk 3 notepad c:\text.txt` opens Notepad on virtual desktop 3 and uses an argument to load `text.txt` automatically.

As detailed on [Windows 10 - virtual desktop startup automation](https://superuser.com/questions/1034074/windows-10-virtual-desktop-startup-automation) .