# launchin programs on windows 10 on different virtual desktops, position them on startup, automatically. How?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization, virtual-desktop

When Windows starts I want programs A,B,C running on Desktop 1 and they should be positioned in a apecific way like A in Fullscreen on Monitor 1, B and C on Monitor 2 splitted.

On Desktop 2 there should also be running programs with predefined window settings.

This hould happen automatically so that i don't have to reconfigure it by myself after every computer restart.

How can i achieve that?

Are there good 3rd party programs?

Comment: Windows 10 Virtual Desktops do not work like that yet. Any program started starts in all Desktops.  I am not sure how much is retained at startup. There is not yet enough capability and flexibility in Virtual Desktops for me to use them much.

Comment: Don't shut down; sleep or hibernate.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1034074/windows-10-virtual-desktop-startup-automation

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Desktops are just a means to organize your daily tasks. Set them up at the beginning of the day and use them as needed.

https://community.windows.com/en-us/stories/virtual-desktop-windows-10

> We all get sidetracked from time to time. Either through the power of
> eye-catching advertising or a promo email from your favorite retailer.
> Using virtual desktop in Windows 10 allows you to expand your desktop
> beyond the physical limitations of the space, organize groups of
> related tasks, and easily switch between  them. Tackling what you want
> to—when you want to—just got a whole lot easier.

However virtual desktops do not survive restart:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_desktop-insiderplat_pc/virtual-desktops-vanish-on-reboot-windows-10/90e49fc8-aae0-4436-ae62-cc41edc1d149

> It is expected that any running apps will close at Shutdown. If you
> were to use Hibernate instead, they might still be running on each
> desktop after powering up again.

Virtual Desktop do not have anything to do with what apps start. All apps started are available in all desktops.  (Just try all your desktops and you will see)

Answer (score 0):

A search for "[virtual desktop monitors](https://superuser.com/search?q=virtual+desktop+monitors)" turned up several discussions.  At first glance I didn't see anything about preconfigured layouts, but I didn't look very far.

Here is an idea you could try.  It uses:

- [UltraMon](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/),
  "a utility for multi-monitor systems, designed to increase productivity and unlock the full potential of multiple monitors."
  It is GUI based, but has a [shortcut feature](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/shortcuts.asp) which I think may help do what you want
  (I don't use UltraMon, so no guarantees).
  A saved shortcut specifies an application's full multi-monitor startup configuration,
  and can be invoked from a command line.
  I have not researched whether there is any other multi-monitor utility with a similar feature.
- [VDesk](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk),
  a utility for switching to a specified virtual desktop and executing a command there.

For each application:

1. Create an [UltraMon shortcut](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/shortcuts.asp) which starts the application on the desired monitor with desired window size, position, etc.
2. Save the UltraMon shortcut as a Windows shortcut (**.lnk** file).
3. Use [VDesk](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk) to run the Windows shortcut on the desired virtual desktop.

Collect the VDesk commands into a script, such as:

```
vdesk on:2 run:"Notepad on monitor 3.lnk"
timeout /t 5
vdesk on:3 run:"Firefox on monitor 1.lnk"
timeout /t 45
...
```

The `timeout` commands give each application time to open its window(s) before the next VDesk command switches desktops again.  You will have to find the right duration by experiment.  For example, my Firefox startup can take some 40 seconds if it decides to auto-update, but usually its windows open sooner and I can tap a key to move on.

I prefer to run my startup script manually, after dealing with the aftermath of any Windows updates during restart.  However, you could invoke it from Task Scheduler or your Windows Startup folder if desired.

You can [search SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/search) for more discussions of VDesk and UltraMon.