# How do i hide a running windows application in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I would like to hide the running windows application so that the running window becomes invisible and the application icon will not be shown on taskbar.

Comment: its depend on that the running app is a system app or is it essential or not. if it is a non-important running app, right click on it in  windows task and choose close.

Comment: Actually i wanted the running app to continue running on the background but become invisible.

Comment: Can you tell what is the running app name?

Comment: @MichaelAtkinson - What you want is not possible.  Any hack that claims otherwise is easily defeated by an Administrator with even a day's experience in the seat.  It is not possible to have a process running and have it NOT appear in the Task Manager.

Comment: AnyDesk . a third party remote destop software

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/43206/how-can-i-hide-an-application-from-the-windows-taskbar

Comment: Here is a small program that you can make that hides/unhides windows. https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2020/05/hidewindow-hides-existing-window-or.html

Answer (score 0):

There are programs that hide running apps from the taskbar but none to my knowledge that would hide them from Task Manager.  There are ways around it though.  If the program you are trying to hide is a stand alone exe, renaming it to something benign would effectively 'hide' it. It really depends on how smart the person that you are trying to hide it from is.  Any decent IT person can track down a running process.  If you just want the program removed from the taskbar there are apps that do just that.