# How to hide a window of a particular app on windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, window

Some apps pop up cmd style black windows (in addition to the "main" window with GUI). These command windows are sometimes not very helpful: they just fill up space on the task bar. It would be better to hide them away.

Is there an easy way to remove a certain window completely from screen and from taskbar, but keeping the program running?

Comment: What App is doing that. I do not see what you describe on my Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

[TrayIt!](https://trayit.en.softonic.com/) might be what you're looking for. It moves the window to the system tray (notification area).

[Another answer here](https://superuser.com/a/43207) has more details. Confirmed to work on Windows 10; even for multi-window apps.